# Overriding a core controller's preDispatch method

Tags: overrides, controllers

I need to override a core controller's preDispatch method.  The core controller inherits from `Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action`, which itself has a preDispatch method that needs to be called.  Since I'm extending from the core controller I want to override, I cannot just call `parent::preDispatch()`, since that would pull in functionality that I'm trying to avoid.

My question is - How can I call an overridden method that is 2 levels higher in the inheritance chain, or am I just going about this the wrong way?

**Update**

Apparently this works:

`Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action::preDispatch();`  (even though that method is not static, I guess you learn something new every day..)

Now my question is: Is there a better way of doing this without having to copy in *all* functionality from the class I am overridding?

The reason I am attempting this is because I was going down [this path](http://rrap-software.com/blog/?p=1), attempting to force Magento to remember address assignments when customers go through multishipping checkout and then subsequently leave.  (FWIW, I found the linked to article great for getting me going in the right direction, but there seems to be a lot missing as far as steps that need to be taken to get this to work).

The controller I'm overriding is the core MultiShippingController which has a redirect back to the Multishipping IndexAction that needs to be avoided.  On a somewhat side-note, I have gotten this functionality mostly complete, save for a few issues (relating to the adding of the first item to the cart and the Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item->getQuoteItem() returning null in the addresses.phtml template, though that is an entirely different discussion).

Comment: Just in case anyone else wanders onto this later and wonders how/why the (seemingly) static syntax is working. I'd refer you to [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31150695/583339) which explains it very well. In short, it's not "static" just like `parent::someMethod()` is not static, but rather specifies part of the inheritance tree to traverse before calling a method in the proper `$this` context of the present class' instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it'd be interesting to know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but I can give you a few pointers without knowing details:

In most cases if the method you're trying to reference does not use `$this`, you can safely call it statically:

```
Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action::preDispatch()
```

But you should probably be doing this via a controller predispatch observer. Magento affords you the ability to do this in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`:

```
abstract class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
{
    // [...]
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        // [...]
        if ($this->_rewrite()) {
            return; // [What is the purpose if this?]
        }
        // [...]

        // [This is where my event needs to be firing, but this code never gets 
        // executed because the controller is rewritten]
        Mage::dispatchEvent(
            'controller_action_predispatch_'.$this->getFullActionName(),
            array('controller_action'=>$this)
        );

    }
    // [...]
}
```

All you have to do is add the full action name onto the end of `controller_action_predispatch`. An example of shoehorning functionality into Onepage Savebilling:

```
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
            <observers>
                <some_unique_name_for_this_event>
                    <class>yourmodel/observer</class>
                    <method>myPredispatchObserver</method>
                </some_unique_name_for_this_event>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
    </events>
```

What's more, in your observer method, you need to accept the observer and you can get the controller *itself* from `getEvent`:

```
<?php

class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer
{

    public function myPredispatchObserver($observer)
    {
        $controller = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I updated my question as to why I'm doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on my phone, but I'd think that you could use any one of several events to remove the redirect from the response object.