# Fix admin backup with observer and max_execution_time?

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, backup

`max_execution_time` blocks the backup function in admin from working. So I thought I can use an observer and `ini_set` to increase the `max_execution_time` for this purpose only.

Questions is which observer would work best for this?

Or how could I find it on myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are generic observers for controller predispatch.

like `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_foo_bar`

Have a look here for the full explanation:

[Overriding a core controller's preDispatch method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5612/overriding-a-core-controllers-predispatch-method)